# Basic randomforest model not printing default values after fitting

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, printing, random-forest, hyperparameters

My following model :

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

forest1 = RandomForestClassifier()

forest1.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Is not printing the default values of the hyperparameters after learning anymore. I did run this kind of command before and I was showing something, do you know how to see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior was changed in 0.23. You can restore the old print-everything behavior globally with:

```py
sklearn.set_config(print_changed_only=False)
```

or temporarily with a context manager:

```py
with sklearn.config_context(print_changed_only=False):
    forest1
```

or just view the parameters of one estimator with:

```py
forest1.get_params(deep=False)
```